# Comparing two tables each column in oracle sql server using procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I Need a procedure to compare two tables of same schema but differnet data

```
Table 1: dep_name,emp_name,sal
Table 2: dep_name,emp_name,sal,status
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag which is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Please, describe with general words what you want to achieve and post sample data as plain text. Also please post your current code and describe what is wrong with it

Comment: Please read and heed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (sample data in lines #1 - 10).

(Though, I'm not sure you know which database you use. Is it Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server? I *presumed* it is Oracle. Also, screenshot doesn't support what you described - there's no `status` column in table 2, but it exists in table 3 which is - I presume (again) - result you want).

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (dep_name, emp_name, sal) as
  3    (select 'Public', 'xxxx', 20000 from dual union all
  4     select 'Drug'  , 'yyyy', 20000 from dual
  5    ),
  6  t2 (dep_name, emp_name, sal) as
  7    (select 'Drug'  , 'yyyy', 10000 from dual union all
  8     select 'Public', 'xxxx', 20000 from dual union all
  9     select 'Police', 'zzzz', 40000 from dual
 10    )
 11  select b.dep_name, b.emp_name, greatest(nvl(a.sal, 0), nvl(b.sal, 0)) sal,
 12    case when a.sal  = b.sal then 'Matched'
 13         when a.sal <> b.sal then 'Unmatched'
 14         else 'New'
 15    end status
 16  from t2 b left join t1 a on a.dep_name = b.dep_name
 17                          and a.emp_name = b.emp_name;

DEP_NA EMP_        SAL STATUS
------ ---- ---------- ---------
Public xxxx      20000 Matched
Drug   yyyy      20000 Unmatched
Police zzzz      40000 New

SQL>
```